# UIImageViewController cameraDevice isn't used each time the camera opens

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I want my app to only use the front facing camera.  So I've implemented the following code.

```
if ([UIImagePickerControllerisCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront]) {
   self.imagePickerController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
}
```

This works the first time I open up the camera (it is using the front facing camera).  But if I cancel the photo and then re-enter into the camera it is using the rear facing camera.

With each cancel / re-enter into camera it switches between front and rear cameras...

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Tr this code .I used this code and it is working fine .Use this code either in button action or viewwillappear or viewdidload and dismiss the camera view properly
    imgPicker =[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imgPicker.cameraDevice=UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
    imgPicker.showsCameraControls = YES;
    imgPicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    imgPicker.delegate=self;
    [self presentViewController:imgPicker
                       animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and resolved the issue in my case by including autorelease on the call to allocate the UIImagePickerController as shown here

UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];

Comment: I cant autorelease since I'm using ARC.